# Extracting chromedriver.exe to java files then pakage import in selenium

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium-chromedriver

I want to run my `selenium script` on my friend system via executable jar.

I am having issue in my `chromedriver` location as it cannot be of my system
Someone suggested that convert your exe chromedriver.exe to java file and import that in package in your selenium script

I don't know how to do that, can anyone help ?

Comment: You can put your jar and chromedriver.exe in same folder and in code put his location like this. `System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","chromedriver.exe");`

Comment: @raul1ro yeah but when i wrap my whole project into executable jar and run it . Chromedriver issues occurs in cmd

Comment: On what OS you try to run?

Comment: Windows 7...it work on my system perfectly but every one else it failed ....main issue is chrome driver location

Comment: On those you try and fail. Google Chrome is installed?

Comment: @raul1ro yes ....

Comment: you can write here what exactly error you get?